# spawn-fcgi: child exited with: 13

Tags: nginx, centos, cgi, munin, spawn-fcgi

```
# spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/munin-fastcgi-html.sock -U nginx -u munin -g munin munin-fastcgi-html
spawn-fcgi: child exited with: 13
```

The .sock is created, but filesize is 0 bytes.
What does code 13 stand for?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to twitter.com/ngourlay I was pointed to a list of system error codes which Linux uses. It could be useful for future reference: http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno.

It is not exhaustive, but tallies in part and is a good starting point. If you're running a Linux system, look around in `/usr/include` for `errno.h`.

An excerpt:

```
#define EPERM        1  /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH        3  /* No such process */
#define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO          5  /* I/O error */
#define ENXIO        6  /* No such device or address */
#define E2BIG        7  /* Argument list too long */
#define ENOEXEC      8  /* Exec format error */
#define EBADF        9  /* Bad file number */
#define ECHILD      10  /* No child processes */
#define EAGAIN      11  /* Try again */
#define ENOMEM      12  /* Out of memory */
#define EACCES      13  /* Permission denied */
```

Answer (score 0):

exit code 13 is permission denied. Try run this command with -n parameter and look at /var/log/nginx/error.log